# About System time in Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

What is the difference between System time and Others time in the Summery pie chart of  Performance Tab of Chrome dev tools and what does specially System time refers to ?

Comment: They've simply [renamed it](https://crrev.com/c/1452774). As for what it comprises, see [this answer](/a/40173057).